# How to reduce horizontal space between navigation icon and title in a jetpack compose `TopAppBar`?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-appbarlayout

I'm making an app bar in jetpack compose but I'm having spacing issues between the navigation icon and the title.

This is my compose function:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DetailsAppBar(coin: Coin, backAction: () -> Unit) {
    TopAppBar(
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = { backAction() }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }
        },
        title = { Text(text = "${coin.rank}. ${coin.name} (${coin.symbol})") }
    )
}
```

This is my preview function:

```kotlin
@Composable
@Preview
fun DetailsAppBarPreview() {
    val bitcoin = Coin(
        id = "",
        isActive = true,
        name = "Bitcoin",
        rank = 1,
        symbol = "BTC"
    )
    DetailsAppBar(coin = bitcoin, backAction = {})
}
```

This is the visual preview of my compose function:
[image: Preview of customized app bar]

This is the space I want to reduce:

[image: Space to reduce in app bar]

Entering the code of the `TopAppBar` compose function I can't see any parameters that allow me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. With the variant of `TopAppBar` you are using, this is not possible. This is because the width of the NavigationIcon is set to the default (72.dp - 4.dp). You can check the implementation of `TopAppBar` and see that it uses the below:

```
private val AppBarHorizontalPadding = 4.dp

// Start inset for the title when there is a navigation icon provided
private val TitleIconModifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
    .width(72.dp - AppBarHorizontalPadding)
```

What you could do is to use the other variant of the `TopAppBar` that gives you much more control in placing the title and icon. It could be something like:

```
@Composable
fun Toolbar(
    @StringRes title: Int,
    onNavigationUp: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    TopAppBar(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(56.dp)
        ) {
            // Title
            Text(...)
            
            // Navigation Icon
            if (onNavigationUp != null) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_back),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(
                        id = R.string.back
                    ),
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.small)
                        .clickable { onNavigationUp() }
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        ...... ,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you need to use have actions as well.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is possible to reduce space between icon and and title but it's a little bit tricky. Just add negative offset to modifier of text like that

```
@Composable
fun DetailsAppBar(coin: Coin, backAction: () -> Unit) {
    TopAppBar(
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = { backAction() }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }
        },
        title = {
            Text(
                text = "${coin.rank}. ${coin.name} (${coin.symbol})",
                modifier = Modifier.offset(x = (-16).dp)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: This works better as per my requirement. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

You must set `offset` for `Text` in `Title`.

`title = { Text(text = "MyApp", color = Color.White, modifier = Modifier.offset(x = (-13).dp)) }`